# react router app hosted on firebase issues 404 error only when trying to access route via address bar

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have a route `https://playlists-22855.firebaseapp.com/client/create` that when trying to access by clicking on the "Topics" link, I can get to just fine.  But when I try to access that route directly by way of the address bar, I get a 404 error.  I was wondering how to correct my code, which can be found [here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1zlw2246w).  Another funny thing is that the code runs just fine on codesandbox as expected, but there it's a create react app app, whereas mine is not.  Thank you.

Comment: There's a difference between Server-side and Client-side. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/905571 and see if that solves your problem

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem too - I fixed it by configuring my app as a single page app. When you originally did `firebase init` you could have selected this as an option. Now, you can do that by manually changing your `firebase.json` file.

You want to add this to your firebase.json

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

so your `firebase.json` will look something like this

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "your-app-name",
    "public": "your-build-directory",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```